# Simple pattern/texture for shading chart elements

Tags: plotting, histograms, filling

If I print the following `BarChart` in black and white, then it is very difficult to tell which bar is "a" and which is "b".

```
BarChart[{{1, 2}}, ChartLegends -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

### Question

How can I put a simple pattern or texture (like stripes or dots) on these bars to differentiate them?  I know that the solution will involve `ChartElements`, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Some downvoters should ask for a mirror

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BarChart[{{1, 2}}, ChartLegends -> {"a", "b"}, 
                    ChartStyle -> {GrayLevel[.1], GrayLevel[.8]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That would work, but I would prefer it there were some sort of pattern as well.  Can you make one have stripes or dots?

Comment: @TysonWilliams Yes, but it won't scale well when you have more bars,and this one will.

Comment: Scaling is definitely needed since this `BarChart` is just a MWE.  My actual `BarChart` does only have two types of bars though.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I put a simple pattern or texture (like stripes or dots) on
>   these bars to differentiate them? I know that the solution will
>   involve `ChartElements`, but I can't figure it out.

May be you need something similar to the following?

```
opts = Sequence[Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0];
Show[BarChart[{{3, 4}}], 
 BarChart[{{3, 4}}, 
  ChartElements -> {Plot[{ArcTan[x], ArcTan[x] + .8}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
                         Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Blue}}, Evaluate@opts],
                    Plot[{-Sin[x], -Sin[x] + .8}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
                         Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Red}}, Evaluate@opts]}]]
```

> [image: barchart]

```
g1[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, 
    ymax_}}, ___] := {{Hue[RandomReal[]], Point@#} & /@ 
   FindClusters[
    Transpose[{RandomReal[{xmin, xmax}, 300], 
      RandomReal[{ymin, ymax}, 300]}], 15], Black, Thin, 
  Line[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmax, ymin}}]}
g2[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, 
    ymax_}}, ___] := {EdgeForm[None], Hue[RandomReal[]], #} & /@ 
  MeshPrimitives[
   VoronoiMesh[
    Transpose[{RandomReal[{xmin, xmax}, 300], 
      RandomReal[{ymin, ymax}, 300]}], {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}], 
   2]
BarChart[{{3, 4}}, ChartElementFunction -> {g1, g2}]
```

> [image]

```
marble := ListCurvePathPlot[RandomReal[{0, 10}, {2000, 2}], PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> False] /. l_Line :> {Hue[RandomReal[]], l};
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, ChartElements -> Table[{marble, All}, {4}]]
```

> [image: m]

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
 ChartElements -> 
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[y^3], y}, {y, 0, 7}, Axes -> True, 
   Ticks -> None, Background -> LightBlue, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ImagePadding -> 0]]
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
 ChartElements -> {{ParametricPlot[{Sin[y^3], y}, {y, 0, 4}, 
     Axes -> True, Ticks -> None, Background -> LightBlue, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0], All}}]
```

> [image: b1]
>
> [image: b2]

The springs with varying thickness and color ([thanks to Vitaliy Kaurov!](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/26846)):

```
spring[heigh_: 5] := 
 Show[With[{amp = .1}, 
    Plot[{amp (3.5 + Sin[(Pi x)/heigh]^(1/2)) + 
       Sin[x^3], -amp (3.5 + Sin[(Pi x)/heigh]^(1/2)) + 
       Sin[x^3]}, {x, 0, heigh}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
     Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Gray}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Directive[ColorData["Rainbow"][x]]], 
     AspectRatio -> 4, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 500}]] /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {y, x},
     PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> False]

BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, ChartElements -> spring[10]]
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, ChartElements -> {{spring[], All}}]
```

[image: pl1]

[image: pl2]

Comment: Nice, +1! I like the spring!

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `ChartLabels` and `ChartLegends` for when the colors may not be easily differentiated.

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {5, 2, 1}},
 ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c"},
 ChartLegends -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

[image]